# How to avoid app asking permission on launch?

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-permissions, android-bitmap

Following are permissions i need in my app.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

My Main Activity

```
`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
//Binding Views
@BindView(R.id.toolbar)
Toolbar mToolbar;
@BindView(R.id.app_bar)
AppBarLayout mAppBarLayout;
@BindView(R.id.ntb_horizontal)
NavigationTabBar mBottomNavigationBar;
@BindView(R.id.vp_horizontal_ntb)
ViewPager mViewPager;
@BindView(R.id.drawer_layout)
DrawerLayout mDrawer;
@BindView(R.id.drawerIcon)
ImageView drawerIcon;
@BindView(R.id.nav_view)
ArcNavigationView mArcNav;
@BindView(R.id.appName)
TextView appName;
boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
@BindView(R.id.searchIcon)
ImageView search;
//Initialization of Classes
SessionManager session;
ApiClient apiClient;
PersonalDetail personalDetail;
//Properties to access
Context context;
public CircleImageView userImageDrawer;
TextView userNameDrawer;
String email, access_token;
boolean showNotificationBadge;
String notificationBadge = "NOT SET";
List<OrgAccount> accountList = new ArrayList<>();
private File outPutFile = null;
private Uri mImageCaptureUri;
Feeds_Fragment feedsFragment = new Feeds_Fragment();
boolean initialCall = true;
GoogleSignInClient mgoogleSignInClient;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

//For Device Contacts
private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 100;



    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    session = new SessionManager(this);
    if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
        Log.d("Am in Main", "Activity Session Checked " + session.isLoggedIn());
        session.checkLogin();
    } else {
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        context = this;
        Common.initializeSubjects();
        HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
        email = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_EMAIL);
        access_token = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer, mToolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        mDrawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        toggle.setDrawerSlideAnimationEnabled(false);
        mArcNav.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        drawerIcon.setOnClickListener(v -> mDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START));
        initStatusBar();
        setNavigationTabBar();
        getKeyboardStatus();
        handleClicks();

    }


}

private void handleClicks() {

    search.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SearchNew.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.anim_dismiss);
    });
}



public void getKeyboardStatus() {
    Keyboardutils.addKeyboardToggleListener((Activity) context, new Keyboardutils.SoftKeyboardToggleListener() {
        @Override
        public void onToggleSoftKeyboard(boolean isVisible) {
            Log.d("keyboard", "keyboard visible: " + isVisible);
        }
    });
}

private void initStatusBar() {

    Window window = getWindow();


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            Window w = getWindow(); // in Activity's onCreate() for instance
            w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBarHello);
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            SystemBarTintManager tintManager = new SystemBarTintManager(this);
            tintManager.setStatusBarTintEnabled(true);
            tintManager.setTintColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white));
        }
  //         if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && 
  Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
  //            
  window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
  //            SystemBarTintManager tintManager = new 
  SystemBarTintManager(this);
  //            tintManager.setStatusBarTintEnabled(true);
  //            tintManager.setTintColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, 
  R.color.white));
  //        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            Log.d("This is diplay", " AM inside Oreo Version");
            window.setNavigationBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, 
  R.color.white));

        }

    }

public void switchFragment(int target) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(target);
}






private void setNavigationTabBar() {
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new 
  FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return feedsFragment;
                case 1:
                    return new Suggestion_Fragment();
                case 2:
                    return new Write_Review_Fragment();
                case 3:
                    return new Notifications_Fragment();
                case 4:
                    return new User_Profile_Fragment();
                default:
                    return new Feeds_Fragment();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "page" + position;
        }
    });
    final String[] colorsForNavigationBar = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation_bar_colors);
    final ArrayList<NavigationTabBar.Model> models = new ArrayList<>();


    models.add(new NavigationTabBar.Model.Builder(
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rating_feed),
            Color.parseColor(colorsForNavigationBar[0]))
            .title("Feeds")
            .build());
    models.add(new NavigationTabBar.Model.Builder(
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.conn),
            Color.parseColor(colorsForNavigationBar[0]))
            .title("SeatMates")
            .build());
    models.add(new NavigationTabBar.Model.Builder(
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.review_one),
            Color.parseColor(colorsForNavigationBar[0]))
            .title("Write Review")
            .build());
    models.add(new NavigationTabBar.Model.Builder(
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.notification),
            Color.parseColor(colorsForNavigationBar[0]))
            .title("Notifications")
            .build());
    models.add(new NavigationTabBar.Model.Builder(
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.user_one),
            Color.parseColor(colorsForNavigationBar[0]))
            .title("Profile")
            .build());

    mBottomNavigationBar.setViewPager(mViewPager, 0);
    mBottomNavigationBar.canScrollHorizontally(-1);
    mBottomNavigationBar.setTitleSize(10 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    mBottomNavigationBar.setBehaviorEnabled(false);
    mBottomNavigationBar.setModels(models);
    mViewPager.getChildCount();
    //TODO:Important Code for hiding the padding
    mBottomNavigationBar.post(() -> {
        final View viewPager = findViewById(R.id.vp_horizontal_ntb);
        ((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) viewPager.getLayoutParams()).bottomMargin =
                (int) 0;
        viewPager.requestLayout();
    });
    mBottomNavigationBar.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(final int position, final float positionOffset, final int positionOffsetPixels) {
            if (position == 3 || position == 2) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    mAppBarLayout.setElevation(0f);
                }
            } else if (position == 0 || position == 1 || position == 4) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP
                        ) {
                    mAppBarLayout.setElevation(3f);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(final int position) {
            mBottomNavigationBar.getModels().get(position).hideBadge();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(final int state) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() != 0) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    } else if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0 && feedsFragment.scrollOutItem > 3) {
        feedsFragment.smoothScrollToPosition();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    finish();
    super.onDestroy();
}


@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.logOut) {
        logOut();
    } else if (id == R.id.all_reviews) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AllReviews.class);
        intent.putExtra("WHERE", "nothing");
        mDrawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (id == R.id.app_new_setting) {
        openSettingsActivity();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manageSeatmate) {
        openManageSeatMateActivity();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_experience) {
        openExperiencesActivity();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_invites) {
        openAllInvitesActivity();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_mySkills) {
        openAllSkillsActivity();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_organization) {
        openOrganizationActivity();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_projects) {
        openProjectsActivity();
    }

    return true;
}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

private void showError(Throwable e) {
    String message = "";
    try {
        if (e instanceof IOException) {
            message = "No internet connection!";
        } else if (e instanceof HttpException) {
            HttpException error = (HttpException) e;
            String errorBody = error.response().errorBody().string();
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(errorBody);
            message = jObj.getString("error");
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message)) {
        message = "Unknown error occurred! Check LogCat.";
    }
    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(mDrawer, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
    View sbView = snackbar.getView();
    TextView textView = sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
    snackbar.show();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ///--

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}


}`
```

And in my `MainActiviy` i do not have anything which requires permission to access external storage but still on app launch it asks for permission for accessing the media, photos etc.

So how can i avoid the permission dialog on launch and pop up it when i need it. Eg : While updating profile photo.

Is it something with session or shared preference ?

I also think that my app crashes when it prompts for permissions.

Following is logcat after crash.

```
`    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:1039)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:1006)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:956)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:917)
    at devlight.io.library.ntb.NavigationTabBar.onDraw(NavigationTabBar.java:1077)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19200)
    at android.view.View.buildDrawingCacheImpl(View.java:18448)
    at android.view.View.buildDrawingCache(View.java:18308)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4240)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4026)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19203)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18150)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18928)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4240)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4026)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.dispatchDraw(ConstraintLayout.java:2023)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18141)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18928)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4240)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.drawChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1254)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4026)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19203)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18150)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18928)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4240)
    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild(DrawerLayout.java:1366)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4026)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19203)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18150)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18928)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4240)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4026)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18141)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18928)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4240)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4026)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18141)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18928)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4240)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4026)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18141)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18928)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4240)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4026)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18141)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18928)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4240)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4026)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19203)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:817)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18150)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:669)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:675)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:783)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3020)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2834)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2387)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1420)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6835)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
2018-10-17 15:18:07.709 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6647)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
2018-10-17 15:18:07.712 V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2018-10-17 15:18:07.713 V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2018-10-17 15:18:07.713 V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 181047867
2018-10-17 15:18:07.716 V/FA: Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 45
2018-10-17 15:18:07.717 V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2018-10-17 15:18:07.717 V/FA: Activity paused, time: 181047884
2018-10-17 15:18:12.015 E/CrashlyticsCore: Failed to execute task.
    java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206)
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsBackgroundWorker.submitAndWait(CrashlyticsBackgroundWorker.java:41)
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.handleUncaughtException(CrashlyticsController.java:321)
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController$6.onUncaughtException(CrashlyticsController.java:301)
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:42)
        at com.instabug.crash.a.uncaughtException(InstabugUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:116)
        at com.instabug.library.a.a.uncaughtException(InstabugUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:28)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1068)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1063)
        at java.lang.Thread.dispatchUncaughtException(Thread.java:1955)`
```

Currently am testing it on Oreo.

Comment: Have a look ath this : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview

Comment: @Bruno So do you mean if i add the requestPermission part wherever i need then the first prompt for permission will not appear?

Comment: no, that's not what he means. Read the link

Comment: @TimCastelijns I got the idea to deal with permissions. And I will add necessary code for it. My concern is only the request dialog should not appear on launch of app. For that what should i do? 

This is totally irrelevant i guess but is there any way like this?

  `<meta-data
     android:name="unityplayer.SkipPermissionsDialog"
     android:value="true"
     />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I was dealing with one library i.e Instabug which was asking for permission to store and share screenshots of app for bug reporting.

Adding this as an answer so someone could dig this way too. I hope this will help someone.